# VideoView is not running in android 5

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar

Please help me!
I wrote this demo for Videoview and it's working in android 4.x. But when i test  in android 5, I don't see nothing on screen. What did I missed? Videoview have apparently not working.
My code looks like this :

```
public class AndroidVideoViewExample extends Activity {
private VideoView myVideoView;
private int position = 1000;
SeekBar seekbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    try {
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.kitkat));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.seekTo(position);
    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            seekbar.setMax(myVideoView.getDuration());
            seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
        }
    });
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (fromUser) {
                myVideoView.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }
    });
}
private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (seekbar != null) {
            seekbar.setProgress(myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        if (myVideoView.isPlaying()) {
            seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: For starters you could implement the catch block for setVideoURI and see if an exception is thrown.

Comment: I did it, but not have any exception, when used function vvideo.seekto...sceen is black in android 5.0.